# calling @font-face in css on local computer

Tags: html, css

I have a local font file folder on my computer, and I am trying to call it in my css. I am using @fontface but i dont know if im doing everything correctly here is my css, any help would be much obliged. thanks .

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "CrimsonText-BoldItalic";
  src: local("C:\Users\joel.CDF\Desktop\depot square\Crimson_Text.ttf");

}
@font-face {
  font-family: "PT_Sans-Web-Bold";
  src: url("C:\Users\joel.CDF\Desktop\depot square\PT_Sans.ttf");
}


#mainheadercontent {
    margin-top: 8%;
    text-shadow: 3px 4px 5px #000;
      font-family: "CrimsonText-BoldItalic";
}
#mainheaderbutton {
    margin-top: 1%;
     font-family: "PT_Sans-Web-Bold";

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/venue2.png" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3></h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/mainimg01.png" alt="Second slide"class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>
                                </h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/mainimg01.png" alt="Third slide"class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>
                               </h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                        </span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-text hidden-xs">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>
                        <img src="images/dslogo1.png" alt="depot square"></h1>
            <h1 id="mainheadercontent">
                        Your elegant and affordable destination<br>for family, business and community events.
                    </h1>
            <div class="button" id="mainheaderbutton">
              <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">MORE ABOUT US</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CHECK AVAILABILITY</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="push">
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks fine.  Are you not getting your expected results?

Comment: I am getting the font style and boldness , just not the italicization. for the crimson text but i cant seem to get anything for the pt sans web bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is incorrect on how you use `local()`.
You use `local()` to call a font that may be installed on the user's computer.

When you call your Crimson Text, it should look something like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: MyFont;
   src: url(ExampleFont.ttf);
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

This should just work locally (assumed from your question) but if you are looking for a solution across all computers then I'll edit my question. Since you only used `local()` on the Crimson text, the PT Sans loads correctly.

If you insist on using the `local()` function, read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).